# Xamarin: VSTS to generate ipa and apk files

Tags: xamarin, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is it possible to use VSTS release generate ipa and apk files and release to the stores ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be Build Definitions to create an `.apk` and `.ipa` in VSTS. You can see the `Build Steps` here:

**Xamarin.Android:**

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/mobile/xamarin#build-steps

Inside the `Build: Xamarin.Android` step, there is a note saying that the project needs a `PackageForAndroid` target.

> Note: The projects must have a PackageForAndroid target.

i.e. `/t:PackageForAndroid`

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/build/xamarin-android

**Xamarin.iOS:**

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/mobile/xamarin#build-steps-1

Inside the `Build: Xamarin.iOS` step, there is an `Create App Package` argument you can use:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/build/xamarin-ios

I would highly advise that you read through each `Build Steps` on both `Xamarin.Android` and `Xamarin.iOS` to get a better idea of what's going on!